# add object with ajax request without reloading the page symfony 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, modal-dialog, refresh

I'm trying to implement my symfony forms / modal ,with ajax to stop reloading page every time time I submit an add/remove and update action, but the problem that I'm not familiar with ajax and I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me understand the concept.

mY entity :

```
<?php

namespace EvalBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Department
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="department")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EvalBundle\Repository\DepartmentRepository")
 */
class Department
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string",unique=true)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * One Department has Many Collaborators.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Collaborator", mappedBy="department")
     */
    private $collaborators;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Department
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

form :

```
<?php

namespace EvalBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class DepartmentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'EvalBundle\Entity\Department',
            'attr' => array('novalidate' => 'novalidate')

        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'evalbundle_department';
    }


}
```

COntroller :

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: sa7noun
 * Date: 5/15/17
 * Time: 12:09 PM
 */

namespace EvalBundle\Controller;

use EvalBundle\Entity\Department;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DepartmentController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Department entities.
     *
     * @Route("/department", name="department_index")
     * @Method({"GET","POST"} )
     *
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $department = new Department();
        $form = $this->createForm('EvalBundle\Form\DepartmentType', $department);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $status = "error";
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($department);
            $em->flush();
            $status = "success";
            //$departments = $em->getRepository('EvalBundle:Department')->findAll();
            return new JsonResponse(array('status' => $status));
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $departments = $em->getRepository('EvalBundle:Department')->findAll();
        /**
         * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
         */
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $result = $paginator->paginate(
            $departments,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            $request->query->getInt('limit', 5)
        );

        return $this->render('EvalBundle:Department:department.html.twig', array(
            'departments' => $result,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /*
     * Creates a new Department entity.
     *
     * @Route("/department/new", name="department_new")
     * @Method({ "POST"})
     */
    /* public function newAction(Request $request)
     {
         $department = new Department();
         $form = $this->createForm('EvalBundle\Form\DepartmentType', $department);

     }*/


    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing department entity.
     *
     * @Route("department/{id}/edit", name="department_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Department $department)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($department);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('EvalBundle\Form\DepartmentType', $department);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);


        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('department_edit', array('id' => $department->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('EvalBundle:Department:edit.html.twig', array(
            'department' => $department,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a department entity.
     *
     * @Route("department/{id}", name="department_delete")
     * @Method({"GET","DELETE"})
     */
    public function deleteAction(Department $department)
    {

//        $response = array(
//            'success' => true,
//            'message' => '',
//            'html' => '',
//        );
//
//          $form = $this->createDeleteForm($department);
//        if ($request->getMethod() == 'DELETE'){
//            $form->handleRequest($request);
//        }
//
        if ($department) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($department);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('department_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a department entity.
     *
     * @param Department $department The department entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Department $department)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('department_delete', array('id' => $department->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm();
    }

}
```

view :

```
 {% extends 'default/superAdminBase.html.twig' %}
    {% block body %}

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #0089db">
                    <h5 style="text-align: center"><b>Départements</b></h5>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-fixed table-paginated">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {% for department in departments %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>{{ department.name }}</b>
                                        <a href="{{ path('department_edit', { 'id': department.id }) }}"
                                           class="btn btn-default btn-circle " style="float: right">
                                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="{{ path('department_delete', {'id': department.id}) }}"
                                           class="btn btn-danger btn-circle remove-item"
                                           data-entity-id="{{ department.id }}" style="float: right" data-toggle="modal">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="infos">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        Etes-vous sur de vouloir supprimer ce Département !
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button href=" #" class="btn btn-info delete-item"
                                                                data-dismiss="modal">OUI
                                                        </button>
                                                        <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">NON</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <div class="navigation text-center">
                {{ knp_pagination_render(departments) }}
            </div>

            <!-- /.panel -->
            <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal-1" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            {% if app.session.flashBag.has('success') %}
                                <div class="aler alert-success">
                                    {% for msg in app.session.flashBag.get('success') %}
                                        {{ msg }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}

                            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"> Ajouter un nouveau département</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-input">
                            {{ form_start(form,{'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal','data-parsley-validate':''}}) }}
                            {{ form_widget(form.name,{'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Nom de département', 'data-parsley-required':'true', 'data-parsley-required-message':'le nom ne doit pas être vide :D'}}) }}
                            <br>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-offset-8 col-lg-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><span
                                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Créer
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {{ form_end(form) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#myModal-1" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary "><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Ajouter un
            département</a>
        {% block javascript %}
            <script src="{{ asset('JS/departmentValidation.js') }}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
```

javascript :

```
$('.btn-send').click(function () {

    $("#myModal-1 form").submit(function (e) {
        var formURL = "{{ path('department_index')}}";
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

               // console.log($.parseJSON(data));
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('pjoih');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

everytime i trying to test this in my browser console i find this error :

> http://evaluation.dev/app_dev.php/%7B%7B%20path('department_index')%7D%7D
>   404 (Not Found)
>   ajaxSubmitDepartment.js:20 failer

Comment: Can you please `console.log(formURL);`? It seems the url in the ajax call is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the Twig variable in your **.js** file. If you want to use twig variable as a javascript variable content, you can use inline script code in your twig view.